# ActionBarSherlock - selecting tab by clicking on other tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an example with 3 tabs and one button.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements TabListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addTab("1", 0, false);
    addTab("2", 1, false);
    addTab("3", 2, false);
    Button cmdClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdClick);
    cmdClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);             
        }
    });

}

private void addTab(String tabTitle, int position, boolean setSelected) {
    ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tab.setText(tabTitle);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab, position, setSelected);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("example", "Selected " + tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("example", "Unselected " + tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("example", "Reselected " + tab.getPosition());
}
```

}

When I click on the button it automatically selects first tab. I would like to automatically select first tab whenever I click on the second or on the third tab. I tried like this

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Log.d("example", "Selected " + tab.getPosition());
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit:

Maybe this example doesn't have any sense but this is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I would like to  have 2 tabs by default, one with title "1" and second one with title "+". When user selects "+" tab I would like to create new tab with title "2" (between tabs "1" and "+") and to automatically select tab "2".

Comment: What if you only call the code when the tab is tab 1 or 2? Right now you call it every which will make an eternal loop in tab 1.

Comment: @Warpzit I also tried that approach `@Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  if (tab.getPosition() == 1 || tab.getPosition() == 2) {
   Log.d("example", "Selected " + tab.getPosition());
   getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
  }
 }` but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to discourage this kind of behavior. This will be VERY confusing for your users and frankly doesn't make any sense.

That said I tried hacking it but it doesn't seem like it's that easy to do. I did following:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                int tabs = mActivity.getSupportActionBar().getTabCount();
                if(tabs > 3) {
                    ActionBar.Tab test = mActivity.getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(2);
                    test.select();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

**Edit:**

For the behavior your describing I think it would be much easier to implement it by  creating your own tabs. You could use radio buttons and/or buttons to implement it easily.

Now this causes the tab indicator to still point at the old tab but the fragment inside is updated to the selected one =/ so not quite there...

Comment: I agree with you that this does not make any sense but this is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I would like to  have 2 tabs by default, one with title "1" and second one with title "+". When user selects "+" tab I would like to create new tab with title "2" (between tabs "1" and "+") and to automatically select tab "2".

Comment: Have you considered making your own tabs instead of using the native tabs for that? That would be much easier and you wouldn't have to hack your way around it.

Comment: @user1716608 You should ask about how to do that instead of your current question. You'd get a much better answer that way.

Comment: First, I would like to thank you for your answers. At beginning I didn't need to add extra tabs so I used native tabs. When I found out that I'm going to need to add new tabs I thought it would be possible with native tabs and it looked very easy.

Comment: @user1716608 Added my comment recommendation with some extra info to the answer. Feel free to vote up :)

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation but I currently have only 6. I will vote up as soon as I have 15 reputation.